# Rotate image using JavaScript after click

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, rotation

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.crossRotate {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  outline: 0;
}

.crossRotate.active {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.crossRotate').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img class="crossRotate" src="https://s31.postimg.org/cf0ip4gd7/logo.gif" alt="Cross Menu button" tabindex="1" />
</body>
</html>
```

Hello, I am trying to make this image rotate 180 degrees after click. I copied almost everything from here: http://jsbin.com/bukacesari/edit?html,css,js,output , but it still doesn't work for me. Can you explain me why and how could I fix this ? This may be silly question, but I have no clue why it doesn!t work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the document to be fully loaded in order to attach a click event, for that you can use one of the following methods:

**1- jQuery ready event:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //DOM is fully loaded. you can safely attach events
});
```

Or the shortcut:

```
$(function() {
    //DOM is fully loaded. you can safely attach events
});
```

**2- Put your script before the closing tag `</body>`:**

```
<body>
    <!-- Your HTML Here -->
    <script>
        //The page can be manipulated safely here !
    </script>
</body>
```

**Example of using `$(function() {....})`:**

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.crossRotate {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  outline: 0;
}
.crossRotate.active {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.crossRotate').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="crossRotate" src="https://s31.postimg.org/cf0ip4gd7/logo.gif" alt="Cross Menu button" tabindex="1" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So I basically have to put that script after CSS file ? Thanks for help anyway, it is working perfectly.

Comment: @Ismail RBOUH is correct, you must add the click function once the page is loaded so that the javascript can actually find your element that it's attaching the click handler to. In your original setup, the javascript is run before the page (and all of it's elements) are loaded, and it doesn't yet see the '.crossRotate' element, thus it cannot attach the click handler to it. The following code is an on load function that runs once the web page is loaded:

    $(function() {
        // write code here
    });

Comment: @LukášJirůšek Please check out the updated answer for further details.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH So basically putting script at the end of body will make sure, that the page will be loaded and THEN the script will be launched, right ? Thanks for updates anyway, you saved my day.

Comment: @LukášJirůšek That's correct. Good luck and you are welcome.